# Bitbucket Unable to access URL error for Git Network operations

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying push certain changes to my git repo. However, it is giving following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://[myusername]@bitbucket.org/[myorganisation]/[myrepo].git/': Operation     timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

Command I am using is:

```
git push origin master
```

The pull command is giving same error. Until recently this was working all fine. Moreover, I am able to perform same operation to my other repo in same organisation successfully.

It would really help if someone could help me understand what is happening.

UPDATE: I contacted BItbucket Tech support. They say that its the problem with my network. I am using Ubuntu Trusty, and my internet functions normally. It seems the problem is related to some sort of firewall somehow.